# Commit all shortcut for Subclipse

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

I have installed subclipse and I have assigned the shortcut ctl-k to the commit command.  Only problem is when I press ctl-k, it only attempts to commit the current file I have open in my editor.  The only way I can get the commit to commit *all* changed/new files is to click the root project folder and press ctl-k.  Is there a way to assign a shortcut to commit all files without having to navigate to the root project folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so. The commit command from Subclipse seems to perform the commit (recursively) on the current selection. Thus you need to select your root folder to commit all your files.

Note that lot of commands works on the current selection.

have you try to press Ctrl+K when for example a directory with no .svn infos is selected ?

Answer (score 1):

Something I just found out today: make sure whichever Command Group your keyboard command belongs to is activated for your current perspective. You can activate the Command Groups in "Customize Perspective".